Trying to extract the real part of a real big and may complex number
I have this order 7 polynomium:
(1/(k^2 M^3))(-λ - Subscript[μ, 
   m]) (k M (λ + Subscript[μ, fg]) (-λ - 
      Subscript[μ, g]) (λ + 
      Subscript[γ, g] Subscript[μ, 
       g]) (-M (A M r γ ϕ - 
         k M r γ ϕ) Subscript[β, m] + 
      M^2 (-k λ + f ϕ - 
         k γ Subscript[μ, a]) (λ + Subscript[μ,
          f]) (λ + Subscript[β, m] + Subscript[μ, 
         i])) - i (A - k) (1 - q) ν Subscript[β, g]
     Subscript[γ, 
    g] (-M (A M r γ ϕ - 
         k M r γ ϕ) Subscript[β, m] + 
      M^2 (-k λ + f ϕ - 
         k γ Subscript[μ, a]) (λ + Subscript[μ,
          f]) (λ + Subscript[β, m] + Subscript[μ, 
         i])) Subscript[ϕ, g])

Using
sol = Solve[c == 0, λ]; 

I'm extracting his roots 7 roots.
Now I must findout if the real part of those roots are negative. (<0).
Using Re[sol[[1,1]]] I thought it would work to at least see the real part and may using a If I could get my conclusions, but I think my expression is gigantic and it's not working as that simple.
Could you please, help me on what should I do?

Please, clarify what you know about the other parameters, do they have any restrictions? That way, it's easier to help you.

Replace subscripts by simple symbols and declare all symbols $Assumptions={x,...}>0$ except $\lambda$ as a first step.  Replacing $\lambda->-\lambda and searching for a real solution could Reduce the degree.

I suggest determining whether the real part of the roots of a polynomial is negative by using Select to filter the roots based on the condition that their real part is less than zero. Here’s how you can approach it, and it may work well for you
(* Simplify the polynomial equation *)
simplifiedEquation = (1/(k^2 M^3))(-λ - Subscript[μ, m]) (k M (λ + Subscript[μ, fg]) (-λ - Subscript[μ, g]) (λ + Subscript[γ, g] Subscript[μ, g]) (-M (A M r γ ϕ - k M r γ ϕ) Subscript[β, m] + M^2 (-k λ + f ϕ - k γ Subscript[μ, a]) (λ + Subscript[μ, f]) (λ + Subscript[β, m] + Subscript[μ, i])) - i (A - k) (1 - q) ν Subscript[β, g] Subscript[γ, g] (-M (A M r γ ϕ - k M r γ ϕ) Subscript[β, m] + M^2 (-k λ + f ϕ - k γ Subscript[μ, a]) (λ + Subscript[μ, f]) (λ + Subscript[β, m] + Subscript[μ, i])) Subscript[ϕ, g]);

(* Substitute specific values for parameters if possible *)
simplifiedEquation = simplifiedEquation /. {k -> 1, M -> 1, Subscript[μ, m] -> 1, Subscript[μ, fg] -> 1, Subscript[μ, g] -> 1, Subscript[γ, g] -> 1, Subscript[μ, a] -> 1, Subscript[μ, f] -> 1, Subscript[β, m] -> 1, Subscript[μ, i] -> 1, A -> 1, r -> 1, γ -> 1, ϕ -> 1, f -> 1, q -> 1, ν -> 1, Subscript[β, g] -> 1};

(* Find numerical solutions *)
numSol = NSolve[simplifiedEquation == 0, λ];

(* Extract roots *)
roots = λ /. numSol;

(* Select roots with negative real part *)
negativeRealRoots = Select[roots, Re[#] < 0 &];

(* Display the roots with negative real part *)
negativeRealRoots



Thank you so much It worked very well!
I was trying to solve without giving values to the parameters, it would help me to automatize it, but in this way I my achieve my goals. Thanks!
